# Connection does not exist with nmcli even if scanned with iwlist

Tags: networking, network-manager, wpa-supplicant, nmcli

I use to run the command to connect to the wifi network `m<essid`

```
nmcli -p con up id myessid
```

Sometimes and for unknown reason,

```
`nmcli` gives me `Error: Connection 'myessid'
```

does not exist even if `myessid` appeared in

```
iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep ESSID
```

I tried to launch `service networking restart` and other commands without success.

What can I do in order for `nmcli` to update its ESSID list?

Comment: I'll check the differences between `nmcli d wifi list` and `iwlist wlan0 scanning` next time

Answer (score 3):

There are three different things:

- an WiFi access point in the scan list. As shown by `iwlist wlp3s0 scan` or `nmcli device wifi list`
- the networking interfaces in your system, like wlp3s0. As shown by `ip link show` or `nmcli device`.
- the connection profiles configured in NetworkManager, as you see them in nm-connection-editor or `nmcli connection show`.

`nmcli con up $CONN` expects a connection. You need to create a connection in NetworkManager in order to activate it. Use nm-connection-editor or `nmcli connection add` and `nmcli connection modify`. See `man nm-settings` for what to configure.

You can also try `nmcli device wifi connect $ACCESSPOINT` which creates a new connection and activates it in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Find and list the available networks/SSID's with:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Find your SSID.
Add the connection with the `-a` flag. The `-a` specifies that the connection which is to be added, so you will be prompted to input the WiFi password.

```
nmcli device wifi -a connect $SSID
```

you may need to run this as root or:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi -a connect $SSID
```